# React Native Element not showing correctly on iOS but does on Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm building a React Native app for iOS and Android. But when I make the bottomtabnavigation and making a custom button in it. The icon and or the views underneath the icon are not showing correctly on iOs but does on android.

Here is the code:

```
<View style={{borderRadius: 50, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 3, top: -25, backgroundColor: '#F6227D'}}>
   <View style={{borderRadius: 50, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 3, top: -3, backgroundColor: '#4A2485'}}>
      <View style={{borderRadius: 50, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 5, top: -3, backgroundColor: '#0551D8'}}>
         <Icon name={'home'} style={{textAlign: 'center'}} size={35} type='material' color={focused ? 'white' : 'black'}/>
      </View>
   </View>
</View>
```

iOS:

[image]

Android:

[image]

Comment: i think you are missing height constraint.

Comment: glad to help..! ill added it as a answer.

Comment: if its ok please accept my answer Jens

Comment: Oh sorry you added a new answer underneath I didn't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing height constant here. add it and try again.

Example:

```
 <View style={{borderRadius: 50, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 3, top: -25, backgroundColor: '#F6227D', height: 100}}>
       <View style={{borderRadius: 50, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 3, top: -3, backgroundColor: '#4A2485', height: 90}}>
          <View style={{borderRadius: 50, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', padding: 5, top: -3, backgroundColor: '#0551D8', height: 80}}>
             <Icon name={'home'} style={{textAlign: 'center'}} size={35} type='material' color={focused ? 'white' : 'black'}/>
          </View>

   </View>
</View>
```